# Como puedo agregar un titulo al lado o debajo de un punto en highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

necesito una pequeña ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo la siguiente grafica:

```js
Highcharts.chart('rendimientosall', {
 colors: ['#00ff6c','#03deec','#f5940a'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'RENDIMIENTO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Acumulado'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['190 cantidad: 6', '240 cantidad: 13', '320 cantidad: 5'],crosshair: true,
  
  labels: { style: { color: 'networking', fontSize:'15px' } }
    },
 
 
 
 
 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Rendimiento (Km)',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: '',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  
  
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
            }
        }
    },legend: {
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0
        },


    series: [{
        name: 'Rendimiento',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: '190',
            y: 112108,
        }, {
            name: '240',
            y: 84289,
        }, {
            name: '320',
            y: 70249,
        }]
    },{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Meta',
  color: 'transparent',
        data: [83712,72341,69638],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
   color: 'red'
        }
    }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="rendimientosall" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:20px;"></div>
```

Lo que necesito hacer es colocar en los puntos ROJOS un texto que diga META osea puede ser al lado del punto rojo o debajo del punto rojo un texto que diga -meta- es posible hacerlo?

Si se fijan en la leyenda el punto rojo tiene como nombre Meta, pero no logro colocar ese mismo nombre dentro de la gráfica, la idea es que se logre ver dentro de la barra debajo del punto rojo o a un lado del punto rojo.

Quedo atento muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para editar la forma en que se muestra el dataLabel debes asignar una función en la propiedad `formatter` de dataLabel, esta función debe retornar un string que va a ser lo que se mostrará en el label. Para armar este string puedes usar el objeto `this` dentro de la funcion que representa a un [Highchart Point](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point)

Adicionalmente yo agregué la propiedad `useHTML` lo que permite agregar etiquetas html en el string que devuelve la función y a estas agregarles `style` o `css class` (esto lo hago por preferencias personales), si usas esto debes considerar que todo el estilo del dataLabel que esta por defecto se pierde y ahora el estilo debes dárselo a los objetos html que uses

```js
Highcharts.chart('rendimientosall', {
 colors: ['#00ff6c','#03deec','#f5940a'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'RENDIMIENTO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Acumulado'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['190 cantidad: 6', '240 cantidad: 13', '320 cantidad: 5'],crosshair: true,
  
  labels: { style: { color: 'networking', fontSize:'15px' } }
    },
 
 
 
 
 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Rendimiento (Km)',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: '',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  
  
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
            }
        }
    },legend: {
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0
        },


    series: [{
        name: 'Rendimiento',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: '190',
            y: 112108,
        }, {
            name: '240',
            y: 84289,
        }, {
            name: '320',
            y: 70249,
        }]
    },{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Meta',
  color: 'transparent',
        data: [83712,72341,69638],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
         color: 'red',
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
              let dataLabelText = `<div style="text-align: center;">
              <div>${this.y.toLocaleString()}</div>
              <div>Meta</div>
              </div>`;
              return dataLabelText;
            }
        }
    }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="rendimientosall" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente, pensé que seria mas complicado sos un groso. saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada estimado